# Can't login via OpenID (blogger.com): non-empty parameters were empty

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

I get this error when trying to login to stackoverflow via OpenID (blogger.com is the provider):

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> The following required non-empty
>   parameters were empty in the
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.PositiveAssertionResponse
>   message: openid.invalidate_handle

Firefox 3.6.3, no custom cookies config, tried clearing cookies, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blogger has some incorrect behavior w/r/t OpenID so we have to run a custom build of DotNetOpenAuth that allows for it.

We lost that custom build in the last deploy, but I just re-deployed with the fixes reinstated -- **it should work now**.

I'll try to get Andrew to make this "relaxing" part of the main trunk as a configuration option, that way it won't get lost again when new versions are released.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I managed to add a gmail openid with a browser where I was still logged in, and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem in Chrome beta (5.0.342.9). I've worked around it by adding my Google profile as an alternate OpenID provider, the URL for that is: `http://www.google.com/profiles/<USERNAME>`